# If a comet-sniffing spacecraft were launched today, could it catch up to newly-discovered ε>3 C/2019 Q4 (Borisov)?

Tags: launch, deep-space, launch-vehicle, comet

As found in [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/33354/7982) to *What makes scientists already so certain that Comet C/2019 Q4 (Borisov) is a comet and not an asteroid?* the orbital parameters of this eccentricity > 3 visitor to our solar system can be found in [Minor Planet Electronic Circular (MPEC) K19RA6](https://www.minorplanetcenter.net/mpec/K19/K19RA6.html). The amateur telescope that discovered this object (and the amateur comet-discoverer themselves) can be seen in [Why is this telescope so short? How hard is it to make such a fast primary?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33337/7982)

Suppose in this post-[ʻOumuamua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOumuamua) age we had had a cometary analysis spacecraft already built and ready to go, so that we could check isotopic abundances from its coma and/or tail to sniff out what another solar system's abundances might<sup>†</sup> be, and a rocket had been procured and dedicated to a short-notice deep-space launch.

**Question:** Would any of the likely rocket candidates and upper stage boosters be able to catch up to Comet C/2019 Q4 (Borisov) assuming it were lauched today, based on it's orbital parameters linked above?

A ballpark answer is fine, it's not necessary to calculate the exact trajectory. I have a hunch that the answer is no, or at least not for a hundred years when the spacecraft will be so far away that we can't receive any data from it, but I don't know.

---

<sup>†</sup>While ε>3 means that unless something unusually happens it's going to *exit* the solar system, it doesn't necessarily mean beyond any doubt that it's *from* outside the solar system.

---

Screen shot of Scott Manley's video [Water Found On Distant 'Super Earth' (or Mini Neptune) AND A New Interstellar Comet!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OG38Ei8R_08) showing an orbitsimulator.com simulation of the comet `13-Sep-2019` using some paramgeters, presumably pretty good ones considering the source. *Click for full size* or watch the video after about `07:10`.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a chance. As detailed in Bill Gray's [FAQ for C/2019 Q4](https://projectpluto.com/temp/2i.htm#probe), the velocity at "infinity" when it leaves the Solar System will be ~32.6 km/s, one of the strongest signs that this was an interstellar object. This is considerably larger than the fastest moving spacecraft, the Voyagers, at 16 km/s. So with current conventional rockets or ion propulsion there is no way to catch up. If the recently selected ESA [Comet Interceptor](http://www.cometinterceptor.space/) had already been launched and was out at the Earth-Sun L2 point, then it might have been possible for it to do a flyby investigation.

Comment: It's a 3D timing problem so I'm not sure that it can be answered solely and conclusively with $v_{\infty}$ alone, However "As it went past us, its path was "bent" by about 34 degrees" suggests that it's not moving towards the Earth but away from it (and/or the Sun). In other words, the comet was discovered too late. That *additional piece of information* would then make an intercept "comet-sniffing" trajectory impossible. Thanks for the ESA Comet Interceptor link, what a great idea!

Comment: I found this short pdf presentation: [Comet Interceptor
A proposed ESA mission to an ancient world](https://www.lpi.usra.edu/sbag/meetings/jan2019/presentations/Tuesday-PM/Jones.pdf) though I don't exactly understand the timing of the "Short cruise and fast flyby near 1 AU" on slide 6 because of the 2D projection, and [this poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnkNg.jpg) in Emily Lakdawalla's [blogpost](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2019/esa-to-launch-comet-interceptor.html).

Comment: What would the remaining delta-v be on the fly-by of the object if it had been at L2? How much faster would the object have been going than the probe-- would it even have been observable (for data that is of scientific importance) if it flew by at 10km/s + velocity difference?